# Update existing values in database

Tags: mysql, database

I created a database table with 5 columns uniqueID (auto increment), name, college, mobile, event(check box of 12 event). So my question is each time a user registers the unique id increments and iI want another event to an already existing uniqueId, is there a possible way to add/update this without going all over to the database and editing it there?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Is this correct: you want to add a new record AND update an existing record when a new user registers?

Comment: okey if i register for an event at first (out of the 12 events) then i will get a uniqueid (which auto increment) and later i want to register another event , for that, is there anyway to update the events with the same uniqueid i got earlier. hope u understood.

Comment: It's not possible to have the same uniqueid on more than one record. If you want to connect the two events, you will need to use another column. `Unique` means only one :)

Comment: thanks a lot. I will post an image and to help you to understand better of what i meant.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0KSnWBbDDGzVEhYaWVuR1BxbVk/edit?usp=sharing .Please check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, following the comments, I suggest you do the following.

You need two tables.

```
user
 - userid (unique, auto-increment)
 - name
 - college
 - mobile

event
 - eventid (unique, auto-increment)
 - userid (not-unique, connects to the user)
```

When a user registers, you create the `user` record and the first `event` record. Then when the user adds another event, you add another `event` record.

UPDATE:

I was trying to teach you slowly, but peterm is right in his comment. The best way is actually this:

```
user
 - userid (unique)
 - fields relevant only to the user

event
 - eventid (unique)
 - fields relevant to the event (e.g., date, place etc)

user_event
 - userid
 - eventid  (where you have a unique key that includes two fields, userid and eventid)
```

You might also have a `college` record too...

But as I said, I was just trying to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: The better way would be to have three tables `users`, `events`, and many-to-many `user_events` to be able to restrict users to signup only to specific exiting events.

Comment: @peterm  I decided not to complicate matters for the questioner :) If you look, the `event` table I've used incorporates the idea of your many-to-many `user_events`. One step at a time :)

Comment: @nick https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0KSnWBbDDGzVEhYaWVuR1BxbVk/edit?usp=sharing check this.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot @nick and for taking time to help me out. Cheers. :)

Comment: As @peterm says, you really want to do it with three tables. The way you are planning to do it stops you doing some really helpful things. If you have three tables, you can select all the users who are registered for any given event. With google file method, you can't :)

Comment: Got It. I am gonna give it a try. :)